# Was there a nation/state which conquered other ones to gather forces and fight against an even greater enemy?

Tags: warfare

I'm writing a fictional story and basically that's the case of one of the kingdoms there: conquering others to become more powerful and fight another nation. I'm asking this question to get some historical evidence if that could work.

I'll try to briefly explain the circumstances:

There is a group of 6 small kingdoms (in a European-ish medieval setting) that share a lot of their culture, since they were one single country in the past. In my story, a powerful foreign nation (let's call it P) is becoming too dangerous and has the potential to beat all these kingdoms in a war (and go even further).

The ruler of one of these kingdoms, who is a woman, thinks that the only way to have a chance against P is using the forces of all the 6 kingdoms together. Since she knows all the other rulers and knows that they probably won't work effectively as a group or accept to be lead by a female, her decision is to conquer all the neighbors and become a central ruler of them all.

Of course, making war to all of these countries would take a lot of resources, time, and result in many human losses. However, she prefers to play clever as much as possible, probably making use of force at first against the weaker kingdoms and later patriotism (mentioning the greater nation they once were) and intimidation to get the support of the other ones. Whenever possible, she will avoid battles, since the idea is to have more soldiers in the end.

I also assume that currently P is "busy" with other conflicts and so the woman will have some "extra time" to conclude this plan of unifying the nation.

**So, my question is**: were there similar situations in real History (even if they were not in Middle Ages)?

Comment: One might say that Modern France is the result of a very long period of conquest and assimilation. As late as 2 hundred years ago if all you had was Parisian language and customs, you might have had a difficult time in a lot of what is France today. There are some analogies with England for about a thousand years..

Comment: The title question says conquered but the body of the question allows patriotism and  intimidation, and mentions avoiding battle if possible. Can you be a little clearer with the specifics as there are potentially dozens of examples which might fit your question as currently worded.

Comment: German unification sort of, although the primary aim was German unification.

Comment: This is actually incredibly common. See for example, the unification of Greece's city states into the [Hellenic League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Corinth) under Philip and Alexander, in preparation for the latter's [invasion of the Persian Empire.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wars_of_Alexander_the_Great) Or, Liu Bei's [conquest of Yi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liu_Bei%27s_takeover_of_Yi_Province) in order to strengthen his forces for taking on Cao Cao. I suggest you narrow down your criteria somewhat since as it stands this question is quite broad.

Comment: I am confused by the many details about your work of fiction. Do you require the leader of the conquering state to be a woman?

Comment: The life of Genghis Khan is an example of this.

Comment: I'll second the view of @Orangesandlemons Germany during WW2 conquered countries and recruited "voluntary" troops from them to fight against Russia.

Comment: Looks a bit like the warring states period of China.

Comment: All empires like to think they've done exactly this.

Comment: Pretty sure the second punic war could count as well, since it was Hannibal's main source of new recruits, they did however hated Rome

Comment: This story is as old as Cain and Abel (or Charlesmagne and Carloman).

Comment: The problem of your story is time restrictions. Unificating kingdowms takes time, double that if it's done by force. The 3rd Reich and Napoleon used forces of the countries they conquered to bolster their own, but at the same time they were fighting partisans and resistence movementes, and when the tide changed these countries quickly jumped onto the enemy rows. The closest thing to what you are thinking is the unification of Greek poleis against the Persian empire... but it didn't arrive in time: Persia invaded Greece twice before the unification. Alexander the Great was lucky Greece won.

Comment: Gengis Khan is not a valid example since he unificated mongol nomad tribes who were used to follow any powerful leader. Whenever he vanquished an enemy his forces would gladly join him with no resentment. As Napoleon, he did used local forces to bolster his own, but they were few and specialized. His might was always his mongol followers. Also, he didn't do that because he feared the chinese empire. He did it because that's what every mongol leader did: they fight each other trying to amass as big an horde as they could. From time to time a Genghis Kan or a Timur Leng emerged by chance.

Answer (score 2):

There are many cases, feel free to add more:

- Napoleon conquerer north of Italy, and recruited forces there for other wars. Later on, after defeating Austria and Prussia, Napoleon invaded Russia. The invasion of Russia was not only with french forces, both flanks of his advance where covered by prussian and austrian forces (north and south).
- As @Steven Burnap says. Genghis Khan is another good example. He unified mongol tribes by war, and with them he invaded other countries. Later on, even chinese engineers where included in his armies fighting in Europe.
- In WWII, Soviet Union used romanian, finish, polish and bulgarian armies as allies at the end of the war against Germany, even though they were enemies (or almost enemies) before.
- Spanish conquest of the new world. Spanish forces were quite small, they actually allied with other tribes to defeat major empires, these states or tribes joined spanish conquistadors either by convenience or defeat. Aztec empire did not fall to a small spanish adventurers.

Comment: When you mention WWII and the Russians, you should mention Germany as well. The Czech-built Pz35(t) / Pz38(t) were the mainstay of the German tank forces for much of the early war period (France, Poland, Russia). Romanian oil. French ports. The list goes on.

Comment: @DevSolar, even though you're right about the use of resources of conquerer nations, my interpretation of the question is regarding to the people who belongs to those conquerer nations.

Answer (score 1):

For me the classic example is [Edward I of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_I_of_England) (aka "Edward Longshanks").

He [conquered Wales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conquest_of_Wales_by_Edward_I_of_England) and once pacified, combined the English and Welsh forces [against the Scots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_War_of_Scottish_Independence) thereby earning the epithet "Hammer of the Scots".

Answer (score 0):

What about Japan in the WW2 period? Gathering up islands to the south such as Singapore. Then they acquired POWs who became slaves,  while getting resources such as rubber. All to compete with a bigger enemy, the US.

Comment: A good example, but with a bit of confusion between cause and effect.  It was the gathering up of resources that brought Japan into conflict with the US - and Britain, which already claimed many of those resources.

Answer (score 0):

Nazi Germany conquering all of Europe and using French, Norwegian, Danish, dutch, Belgian, Czech, Austrian, etc and even Yugoslav troops

Comment: Did that actually result in a net gain of men and materiel for Germany, considering the losses involved in capturing and occupying those countries?

Comment: @SteveBird Certainily a net gain in material (at first) - Nazi Germany's rearmament was unsustainable without looting the rest of Eurrope for it.

Comment: In Yugoslavia no, but the others were easy

Answer (score 0):

Too many to count. In addition to those in other answers:

- The Republic of Rome - conquered Italy and under Marius enfranchised Italian legionnaires following twenty years of service.
- Philip of Macedon united the city-states of Greece; his son Alexander conquered the Persian Empire with a unified army of Macedonians and Greeks.
- Alfred King of Wessex united the Saxon petty kingdoms of England into a nascent version of that state to repel the Danish invaders.
- Bismark, Chancellor of Germany, used the threat of Austrian and French hegemony to unify the petty states of Germany into the Second Reich under Kaiser Wilhelm I.
- Tecumseh and his brother, *the Prophet*, attempted to unify the tribes of the Ohio Valley and Lower Great Lakes basin as allies of the British against the United States.
- Sitting Bull attempted to unify the Plains tribes against the United States - though he also failed.
- [*The Commancheria*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comancheria) may be another example from 19th century U.S. history.
- Barbarossa's (re-)unification of the Holy Roman Empire after a long civil war prior to joining the Third Crusade against Saladin.
- Charles Martel fought a long civil war to unify the Franks - just in time to defeat the Moors at the Battle of Tours.
- The Iroquois Confederacy conquered everything South of the Great Lakes from Illinois to Upper new York State and Maryland, as well as SW Ontario, as part of their war against the French.
- Hitler's occupation of the Rhineland, *anschluss* with Austria, and absorption of the Sudetenland prior to World War Two. These regions, unlike those conquered afterwards in Western, Central and Eastern Europe, were eager participants in the Wehrmacht and S.S. during World War Two.

Some may argue that a few of the above were accomplished without blood being shed in battle - yet the great military theorists have always recognized that the greatest victory is exactly that - one won so decisively in advance that the enemy succumbs **without battle**:

> *The greatest victory is that which requires no battle.*
> Sun Tzu - **The Art of War**
>
> *War is the continuation of politics by other means.*
> Carl von Clausewitz - **On War**

Comment: All of those Italian legionnaries were in fact enfranchised before 20 years were up from the date of Marius's promise, since he made the promise in 107 BC and *essentially all free (i.e., not slave) Italians were made citizens by 88 BC to end the Social War.*

Answer (score 0):

To give a specific example from Roman history, the [Social War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_War_(91%E2%80%9388_BC)) (91-88 BC), uniting Italy as a political entity (as opposed to a patchwork of allies and colonies), was immediately followed by [war against Mithridates VI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Mithridatic_War) in Asia.